# Object of class Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler could not be converted to string

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I am trying to run my first functional test in Symfony2 using the DemoController.

If I load the page from the browser the data displayed are correct.
But if I try to run the test by using the command `phpunit -c app` I got the following error message:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Blog\CoreBundle\Tests\Controller\AuthorControllerTest::testShow
Object of class Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler could not be converted to string
```

Here is my AuthorControllerTest class:

```
<?php

namespace Blog\CoreBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

/**
 * Class AuthorControllerTest
 */
class AuthorControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * Test show author
     */
    public function testShow()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        /** @var Author $author */
        $author = $client->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('ModelBundle:Author')
            ->findFirst();
        $authorPostCount = $author->getPosts()->count();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/author/'.$author->getSlug());

        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful(), 'The response was not successful');

        $this->assertTrue($authorPostCount, $crawler->filter('h2'), 'There should be '.$authorPostCount.' posts');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the message error when you execute the following line:

```
$this->assertTrue($authorPostCount, $crawler->filter('h2'), 'There should be '.$authorPostCount.' posts');
```

The error is due to the wrong parameters you pass to assertTrue function. This is used just to assert that a condition is true.

To assert the number of elements your should use the function assertCount.

```
$this->assertcount($authorPostCount, $crawler->filter('h2'), 'There should be '.$authorPostCount.' posts');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$crawler->filter('h2')` return an object. To compare content of it use `text()` method to extract information. Try

```
$this->assertEquals($authorPostCount, $crawler->filter('h2')->text(), 'There should be '.$authorPostCount.' posts');
```

**EDIT:**

And if you just want to compare number of posts (not the `<h2>` node value but number of `<h2>` nodes on page) use `count()`

```
$this->assertEquals($authorPostCount, $crawler->filter('h2')->count(), 'There should be '.$authorPostCount.' posts');
```

or just

```
$this->assertCount($authorPostCount, $crawler->filter('h2'), 'There should be '.$authorPostCount.' posts');
```